Can't Load my learning model into my flask environment
I am trying to load my model that I made on Kaggle into a Flask environment but I am having trouble figuring out the issue. I am not sure if it is a library issue with different versions.
This is the error that I am getting when I am attempting to load in the mode.
These are the libraries that I have installed and its not working still.
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import numpy as np
#import keras.models
#from keras.models import model_from_json, Sequential
#from keras.layers import  Dropout 
#import tensorflow.keras.layers as L
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json
#from keras.src.models.sequential import Sequential
import os
import pickle
import librosa

This is the code that I am using to try and read in the model.
json_file = open('Backend/kaggle/CNN_model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("Backend/kaggle/best_model1_weights.h5")

This the how I am attempting to save the model.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("CNN_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("CNN_model_weights.h5")
print("Saved model to disk") 


I have it working in my Kaggle to be able to load in the model. I am only having issues with loading it into my Flask.
I am thinking that I am having issues with Kaggle libraries being behind from what I have installed but I thought loading it in as a .json would be able to avoid that.
I know that the libraries I am using and Kaggle are different versions, but I thought that the .json model wouldn't be affected to getting loaded in. This is my first time attempting to load in a learning model into Flask.
This the new error that I am getting. I used from tensorflow.python.keras.models import model_from_json and it fixed my previous issue.
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Unknown layer: BatchNormalization. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
  File "/Users/franciscovara/Documents/CSCI490/Backend/app.py", line 41, in <module>
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

Update:
I added the library
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

however I get a different error stating that it cant be used.
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/franciscovara/Documents/CSCI490/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 247, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/franciscovara/Documents/CSCI490/Backend/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' (/Users/franciscovara/Documents/CSCI490/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py)


Try using from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json when loading.

Also make sure your paths are correct too.

@twalow I've used tensorflow.keras.models but I get an error that the library doesn't exist and get the same error of sequence not being able to be found. I have it in my code above commented out because I've tried it and it doesn't work.

Pretty sure you just need tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization as your error specifically mentions it cant identify BatchNormalization as a layer. use - from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

If you are getting an error you need to ensure you have the latest tensorflow.

pip install --upgrade tensorflow
I just tried that library on my computer and it loads just fine w/ no errors.

@KaranShishoo Thank you for the suggestion I attempted to do that and I get a different error now.

@Frankievara you seem to have mixed up the 2 ways to import batch normalization  Use - from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization,You seem to have mereged it with another import - from tensorflow.python.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization. Just use the keras import

@KaranShishoo are you suggesting using keras.layers? I have to use from tensorflow.python.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization, if I remove the .python. I get an error about the library not being able to be loaded in. This avoids that error. I am not sure it is because i am using VS code.
